# What does a *Locked* folder mean in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I thought that folders with a lock symbol next to them represented either an *encrypted* or a 
*compressed* file.

However according to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/29424/what-do-green-folders-mean-in-windows-7-explorer), I was wrong.

**What does this locked folder mean under Windows 7?**

[image: Screenshot showing lock icon]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it means that it has restricted permissions, i.e. some users can access it, but others can't.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, I think it means that the folder is shared with nobody (i.e. you are the only one who has access to it.)
If you right-click a folder in Windows 7, and navigate to the "Share with" option, you can check "Nobody" has the lock icon beside it.