# Changing the color of compressed items in explorer search results

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-management

I have enabled both of options to compress NTFS files, and to show affected items with an [alternative color](https://superuser.com/questions/29424/what-do-green-folders-mean-in-windows-7-explorer/573891#573891) under *Exprorer***->***Tools***->***Folder Options*. The issue I'm having is with the default color. To change the undesired presentation-color of files, a certain registry entry can be populated with four "RGB bytes"

```
CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\altColor
```

However, this affects the regular list of files in explorer. My intention is to change the color in the list of search results. Is there a similarly straight forward way to specify 
the color of compressed files in the search plugin?

***Strawberry-perl-*.msi should be orange***

[image: Blue Strawberry]

What this screen shot shows:

- illegible blue color
- more suitable orange color
- registry value manipulated to get the desired color
- the hex of those four bytes in GIMP color selector